# RapidAPI: How can I find hotel_id in booking.com?

Tags: python, python-requests, rapidapi, booking.com-api

I am using API from RapidAPI for booking.com. I would like to get reviews of a hotel but I do not know how I can find `hotel_id` (required parameter) for a particular hotel?

```
import requests

url = "https://booking-com.p.rapidapi.com/v1/hotels/reviews"

querystring = {"hotel_id":"1676161","locale":"en-gb","sort_type":"SORT_MOST_RELEVANT","customer_type":"solo_traveller,review_category_group_of_friends","language_filter":"en-gb,de,fr"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "booking-com.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "1bed4aac31mshcd4d969233d7d7dp129f0bjsn58eea903e6c2"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: if you're querying for a particular hotel_id, then I'm not able to understand where you want to find it? the output from `requests` would be a string of dict that can be loaded as json using `json.loads(response)`

Comment: You may have accidentally leaked an API key in your question, please revoke this key to stop your account being compromised. Its not enough just to edit the question removing the key.

Answer (score 2):

You can find hotel_id using the below RapidAPI.

Get available hotels by the filter. Indicate the destination_id and dest_type -> use @Search locations endpoint, check-in and check-out date, number of adults and children. For possible filters use @Filters for search

```js
import requests

url = "https://booking-com.p.rapidapi.com/v1/hotels/search"

querystring = {"room_number":"1","order_by":"popularity","filter_by_currency":"AED","checkout_date":"2022-07-02","checkin_date":"2022-07-01","units":"metric","adults_number":"2","dest_id":"-553173","dest_type":"city","locale":"en-gb","children_number":"2","children_ages":"5,0","page_number":"0","include_adjacency":"true","categories_filter_ids":"class::2,class::4,free_cancellation::1"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "booking-com.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "0195db92d0msh8afac0130adb2c4p1087e9jsn2aeab9e0aa0f"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

The result is like below.

```js
"result": [
    {
      "id": "property_card_791664",
      "hotel_name": "Cheval Thorney Court at Hyde Park",
      "class_is_estimated": 0,
      "hotel_has_vb_boost": 0,
      "district": "Kensington and Chelsea",
      "cant_book": null,
      "distance_to_cc": "4.00",
      "mobile_discount_percentage": 0,
      "is_mobile_deal": 0,
      "is_free_cancellable": 0,
      "countrycode": "gb",
      "latitude": 51.5011118011927,
      "districts": "1545,29,44,333,2280",
      "city_name_en": "London",
      "min_total_price": 379.24,
      "hotel_id": 791664,
      ...
```

You can get hotel_id from the result.

Visit https://rapidapi.com/tipsters/api/booking-com/tutorials/booking-api-tutorial-1

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Nikita. Is there a different way of getting the hotel_id?

Comment: Hello, how can you put a name of city in the search api ? we have a dest_id but if you want put "Paris" or "London" how can you search it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you two methods: one is manual, and the other involves using code in Python. Understanding the first method will help you realize how the second one works.

## Manual

1. Open the hotel page on booking.com where you wish to find the
   hotel_id.
2. Right-click on the page and select Inspect to open the Chrome
   Developer Tools.
3. Navigate to the Console tab within the Developer Tools.
4. Enter the following JavaScript command and press Enter:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="hotel_id"]').value
```

This command looks for an `input` element with the `name` attribute set to `hotel_id` and retrieves its `value`, which corresponds to the hotel's ID.

## Python

### Prerequisites:

Ensure you have `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` installed in your Python environment. If not, you can install them using pip:

```bash
pip install requests beautifulsoup4
```

### Python Code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Replace 'YOUR_HOTEL_PAGE_URL' with the actual URL of the hotel page on booking.com
url = 'YOUR_HOTEL_PAGE_URL'

# Fetch the content of the hotel page
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the input element with name='hotel_id' and get its value
hotel_id = soup.find('input', {'name': 'hotel_id'})['value']

print(f'The hotel_id is: {hotel_id}')
```